# How to allow files in p4ignore

Tags: perforce, gitignore, ignore, p4v

I want to ignore all files whithin the `Binaries` folder except dll files in that folder.

```
# Ignore all files and folders
Binaries/*

# Dont ignore dll files
!Binaries/*/*.dll
```

With this, all files and folders get ignored. Even dll files.

But i want to allow dll files. For example

```
Binaries/Win64/someName.dll
```

Should NOT be ignored.

Please help. P4 ignore file name is ".gitignore"

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
# Ignore everything under Binaries except .dll files
Binaries/
!Binaries/**.dll
```

Testing this out gets me:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 add -n Binaries/foo
//stream/main/Binaries/foo#1 - opened for add
c:\Perforce\test\Binaries\foo - ignored file can't be added.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 add -n Binaries/Win64/someName.dll
//stream/main/Binaries/Win64/someName.dll#1 - opened for add
```

which seems correct for your use case.

Comment: does it matter where .gitignore file is placed? given you example mine is placed in `c:\Perforce\ ` directory and not in `c:\Perforce\test\ `

Comment: Run `p4 set P4IGNORE=.gitignore` to tell `p4` the name of your ignore file.

Comment: I already did that, and it works for everything else. except for `!Binaries/**.dll`. I figured I have to write the path explicitly to make it work. i.e `!MyProject/Binaries/Win64/*.dll` and so on. It's not good but it gets the job done.